# How do you use CDVPluginResult() in swift to return an array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift2, cordova-plugins

I'm following this howto to create a cordova plugin using swift:
http://moduscreate.com/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-for-ios/

My version seems to work--I can use `CDVPluginResult()` to return the correct data to the JS app, but I have to serialize the data in `ios` and then `JSON.parse` in JS.

```
// swift
pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
        status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
        messageAsString: data.toJSON()
)
self.commandDelegate!.sendPluginResult(
  pluginResult,
  callbackId: command.callbackId
)

// JS
var successCallback = function (result) {
    try {
        var data = JSON.parse(result);
        callback(null, data);
    }
    catch (err) {
        callback(err, result);
    }
};
var errorCallback = function (err) { return callback(err, undefined); };
exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "myPlugin", "getData", [arg0]);
```

But how do I use `messageAsArray` or `messageAsArrayBuffer` or `messageAsMultipart` to return my data to `JS` as an `object[]`? Nothing seems to work...

example:

```
class MyObj: NSObject, NSCoding {
   let uuid: String

   // see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html
   func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
       aCoder.encodeObject(self.uuid, forKey: "uuid")
   }

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       guard
           let uuid = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("uuid") as! String?
           else {
               return nil
       }
       self.uuid = uuid

       super.init()
   }

   required init(uuid: String) {
       self.uuid = uuid
       super.init()
   }
}

var data : [MyObj] = [...]
pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
  status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
  // messageAsString: toJSON(data)

  // How do I return swift [MyObject] as JS object[]?
  messageAsArray: data.map({o in NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(o))

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the messageAs argument to return

- JSON object from a type erased Swift dictionary: `[AnyHashable : Any]`
- JSON array (of objects) from a Swift array (of dictionaries): `[[AnyHashable : Any]]`

Example:

```
    let foo = ["foo": 123] as [AnyHashable : Any]
    let bar = ["bar": 234] as [AnyHashable : Any]
    let baz = ["baz": 456] as [AnyHashable : Any]
    let array = [foo, bar, baz]
    let pluginResult = CDVPluginResult(
        status: CDVCommandStatus_OK,
        messageAs: array
    )
```

Returns the object `[{foo:123}, {bar:234}, {baz:456}]` in the browser callback.